# Populating the combobox from database

Tags: javafx

I want to build a `ComboBox` that is populated with data from database but it's not working.The Scene Builder is fine i made the fxid:comboBoxx and onAction:fillComboBox2 and its running,but i dont have any data,just blank.I dont know where is the problem,i tried everything i know.

```
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML       
    private ComboBox comboBoxx;

    final ObservableList options = FXCollections.observableArrayList();



  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

  }

  public void fillComboBox2() {
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=TestDB;integratedSecurity=true;";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        String query = "select artikulli from product_table";
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();
        while(set.next()){
            options.add(set.getString("artikulli"));
        }
        statement .close();
        set.close();

    } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(JavaFXExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A more detailed description than "it's not working" would be helpful. Additional details are needed as well: How are you invoking the `fillComboBox2`? How is `options` connected to the `ComboBox`? Also narrowing down the issue is much easier to you than it is for us, so please invest some time using a debugger and/or adding a few statements doing output to the console. You could e.g. find out, if the db query is working or not. ([Edit] the question to add this info.)

Comment: You set your `onAction()` to the `fillComboBox2()` method? That means the database is being queried every time you click on the `ComboBox`. Also, the code you provided never binds the `options` list to the `ComboBox`. I recommend working through a few JavaFX tutorials to get a better feel for how the UI elements work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to address here. First of all, you are never actually telling your `ComboBox` where to find the data it's meant to display.

This is done using the `comboBoxx.setItems()` method. This is easy to do within the controller's `initialize()` method.

Also, you stated that you set the `onAction` property of the `ComboBox` to your `fillComboBox2()` method. This is not correct. Doing so will cause the `fillComboBox2()` method to be called every time you click on the dropdown for the `ComboBox`.

Instead, you should fill the `ComboBox` when loading the scene.  So, remove the `onAction` definition from your `FXML` document.

Lastly, it would be a good idea to change that method entirely. In my updated code below, you'll see that I've changed it to a `private` method that returns a `List<String>`. We can use that `List` to populate the `ComboBox`.

Now, when the scene is being loaded, the `comboBoxx.setItems()` method is called, and the `List<String>` from the `getData()` method is used to populate it.

The code below also has some comments to help explain the flow.

> **THE CODE**

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FXMLController {

    // If you ComboBox is going to display Strings, you should define that datatype here
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> comboBoxx;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // Within this initialize method, you can initialize the data for the ComboBox. I have changed the
        // method from fillComboBox2() to getData(), which returns a List of Strings.
        // We need to set the ComboBox to use that list.
        comboBoxx.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(getData()));

    }

    /**
     * Here we will define the method that builds the List used by the ComboBox
     */
    private List<String> getData() {

        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=TestDB;integratedSecurity=true;";

        // Define the data you will be returning, in this case, a List of Strings for the ComboBox
        List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            String query = "select artikulli from product_table";
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);

            ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();

            while (set.next()) {
                options.add(set.getString("artikulli"));
            }

            statement.close();
            set.close();

            // Return the List
            return options;

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```